# How do I automatically retry an SFTP connection attempt?

Tags: bash, sftp

Is there an option to have Bash retry an SFTP connection n number of times or for x seconds? I'm unable to find any info on making a shell script automatically retry, regardless of the cause of error (server is down, bad password, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to try it three times:

```
c=0; until sftp user@server; do ((c++)); [[ $c -eq 3 ]] && break; done
```

---

Long version with error message:

```
c=0
until sftp user@server; do
  ((c++))
  if [[ $c -eq 3 ]]; then
    echo error
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Once the loop is finished and a connection is never established, how do I make it throw an error? I know this is kind of outside the scope of the initial question, but when I ran `if [[$? != 0 ]]; then echo 'error'; exit 100; fi;`, an error wasn't caught

Comment: Check the counter $c. Append `; [[ $c -eq 3 ]] && echo error` or replace `break` by `echo error && break`.

Comment: I'm running that if statement after the complete `sftp` command. So I ended up doing `if [[ $c -eq 3 ]]; then echo 'error'; fi;`. Would you recommend that, or putting the if statement into the `sftp` connection line?

Comment: How do I do this with a heredoc? I'm struggling to add in a heredoc to the end of the sftp connection line

Comment: for heredoc (or other complex behaviours) I would put the sftp call in a function with `return $?`, and use that inside the while

Answer (score 2):

You can use `until` loop.

```
STAT=1

until [ $STAT -eq 0 ]; do 
   sftp user@host
   STAT=$?
done
```

Above syntax will continue till sftp succeeds, If you need for certain number of times then you can use a `while` loop with counter.

```
counter=1
while [ $counter -gt 0 ]; do 
    sftp user@host
    counter=$(($counter-1))
done
```