# How do I catch an error from a Bash sftp connection?

Tags: bash, sftp

How do I try an SFTP connection with a heredoc 3 times and catch an error? How do I restructure this to be proper? Error is being thrown on the first semicolon on the last line right before `do`

```
count=0; until sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem server@server.com <<END
cd subfolder
END
; do ((count++)); [[ $count -eq 3 ]] && echo 'error' && break && exit 64; done;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 until echo "cd subfolder" | sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem server@server.com
```

Or take a look at sftp's option `-b`.

Comment: So how do I do this x number of times? I've been trying to implement this with your answer to my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32787763/1175788) but can't figure it out. And I don't think `-b` helps me here